# Google map doesn't displayed after page load

Tags: javascript, google-maps

In my store locator page, google map appears for a few minutes and disappears , 
in console I get the error:

> Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
>   Your site URL to be authorized: https://preprod.site.com/magasins

How could i resolve this issue?

Comment: show what you tried

Answer (score 1):

it's means that  google not support any more free google maps. Now you need pay for this in account and add your site link for this map.

https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/

Comment: it appears in the home page , but not in stores pages

Comment: i think you just finished your limit  https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/usage-limits#web-service-apis.    

Shared daily free quota of 100,000 requests per 24 hours; additional requests applied against the annual purchase of Maps APIs Credits.

Comment: and in description, google says about commercial usage, that's mean google detect your stores pages like commercial

Answer (score 1):

The same issue i was facing couple of months back and that is because end of free google map usage effective from i think June 11, 2018. Google does not provide free google maps now. You need to have a valid API key and valid billing used, which may give you 200$ of free usage.

Refer link for more details:
    [Google Map Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/)

If you are upto using only maps with specific user, you can try other map tools.